# Convert output to JSON in Python

Tags: python, json

I have executed few Linux commands using Python code. Please refer the code below with the output.

```
import os

uptime_from_top_command = "top -c -b -n1 | head -1 | cut -d ' ' -f 4-6 | sed -e 's/,//'"
uptime = os.system(uptime_from_top_command)

load_average_from_top_command = "top -c -b -n1 | head -1 | cut -d ',' -f 4-6 | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//'"
load_average = os.system(load_average_from_top_command)
```

I got the below output.

```
up 100 days
load average: 0.06, 0.04, 0.00
```

I need to convert this output into the below JSON format and store it inside a JSON file.

```
{
    "uptime": "100 days",
    "load average": {
        "1_min": "0.06",
        "5_mins": "0.04",
        "15_mins": "0.00"
    }
}
```

Note - If the uptime of a server is less than 1 day, then it'll be displayed as `up 12:45`(for example). In that case, it should be converted to a JSON file in below format.

```
{
    "uptime": "12:45",
    "load average": {
        "1_min": "0.06",
        "5_mins": "0.04",
        "15_mins": "0.00"
    }
}
```

I mean, it should accept both the formats.

Please could someone help me how to achieve this?

Comment: Note that the `os.system` command does not capture the output of the subprocess. You're going to need to investigate the `subprocess` module.

Comment: @larsks thank you! I already got the required output in Python for those OS commands. Below is the same.

up 100 days
load average: 0.06, 0.04, 0.00


I just need to convert this output into the below JSON format and store it inside a JSON file.


{
    "uptime": "100 days",
    "load average": {
        "1_min": "0.06",
        "5_mins": "0.04",
        "15_mins": "0.00"
    }
}

Comment: "I already got the required output in Python for those OS commands." Not with that code you don't. Per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system), the `os.system` call only returns an integer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `re` module to parse the string output. For example:

```py
import re

s = """\
up 100 days
load average: 0.06, 0.04, 0.00"""

out = {
    "uptime": re.search(r"up ([^\s]+(?: days?)?)", s).group(1),
    "load average": dict(
        zip(
            ("1_min", "5_mins", "15_mins"),
            re.search(r"load average: ([^\s]+) ([^\s]+) ([^\s]+)", s).groups(),
        )
    ),
}

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{
    "uptime": "100 days",
    "load average": {"1_min": "0.06,", "5_mins": "0.04,", "15_mins": "0.00"},
}
```

---

EDIT: To save data in Json file:

```py
import re
import json

s = """\
up 100 days
load average: 0.06, 0.04, 0.00"""

out = {
    "uptime": re.search(r"up ([^\s]+(?: days?)?)", s).group(1),
    "load average": dict(
        zip(
            ("1_min", "5_mins", "15_mins"),
            re.search(r"load average: ([^\s]+) ([^\s]+) ([^\s]+)", s).groups(),
        )
    ),
}

with open("data.json", "w") as f_out:
    json.dump(out, f_out, indent=4)
```

Saves the data to `data.json`:

```json
{
    "uptime": "100 days",
    "load average": {
        "1_min": "0.06,",
        "5_mins": "0.04,",
        "15_mins": "0.00"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrej Kesely for the suggestions. Basically this conversion should be done and saved in a JSON file. It shouldn't be in STDOUT. Could you please advise me on achieving this?

Comment: @RaviTejaKothuru See my edit.